# Constant Voltage Load

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet

[image]

Can someone tell me if am I right?
In constant voltage mode the op amp compares the voltage on the non-inverting input with the voltage on the inverting input and when U+ is larger than U- the load MOSFET turns on?

Comment: Replace R5 with CV diode

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you have described is a shunt regulator. Try looking in that direction and note that a lot of semiconductor chip suppliers have these as products. You might also want to look up zener diode - it is also a shunt regulator.

> Can someone tell me if am I right?

Yes, you are right although a circuit like this could be very unstable.